# What is to be written in the class description

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

How to describe a class is my question? When you start a class in bluej there's always a documentation comment for the description of the class. What is to be written in that description?

For example I have a class called Economy that extends an abstract class Structure and the abstract class Structure implements an interface Basic. So what should I write in the description of the class Economy?

Comment: Imaging your a developer looking for a class which might help you to do your task. Then you find the class `Economy` ... what would you like to know, now? Maybe the purpose of this class? How it should be used? If it is immutable and/or thread-safe (this might be too much for your purpose here) and other stuff. Think about other developers and what they need to know about your class. Then write that.

Comment: I'd suggest to check on existing Javadoc from JDK and other libraries to get a feeling for useful content in the class description.

Comment: @Tom but I never really understood what exactly is to be written ..... Can you please give an example...maybe with some other example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Comment: @Stefan ....... can I write that my class Economy basically finds out the charges for travelling in Economy class in an airplane ...... but I think this is the description of the method that I have used in my class

Comment: @Abcd and stack doesnt do well with opinion based questions either. Jaggerneister answering you with "less comments,go try agile"... But i can also answer with "more conments, go learn the rational process"  these answers are 100% based on preference. This is not the type of questions Stack wants, as we prefer questions that will help the next users. All your questions are very specific to YOU, and extremely unlikely to ever be searched. That makes them bad quality questions for us. Consider reading the help center, really. This site has guidelines, learn them and respect them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first thing to understand is ... one should actually  write as few comments as possible. Instead: write code that can be read and understood and used without having (a lot) of additional comments around them.

Example: the names you choose "Structure" and "Basic" are very much ... meaningless. Those names do not tell anything about the intended behavior that one can expect from the corresponding class and the interface.

Thing is: comments lie. They add an extra quality to your source code; but a quality that can't be checked automatically. Thus it is very easy for that information to get out of sync with the things the code **really** does.

In other words: it can be perfectly OK to put an empty or very short description on a class. Besides: there is [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) that gives you guidance on "putting only a single responsibility" into each class. So, the core point of a "class description" would be to name/describe that one responsibility of the corresponding class.

Comment: can I write that my class Economy basically finds out the charges for travelling in Economy class in an airplane ...... but I think this is the description of the method that I have used in my class

Comment: Another good example: your name "Economy" doesn't give the slightest hint that it is about computing charges. If you are really interested in learning how to do things in a better way, I would recommend you to search the net for "Agile principles and patterns ... in C#" by Robert Martin. The PDF of that book is available from the net ... and have a close look at the "case study" he presents. Just reading chapter 26 might give you an idea how alone good naming of classes/interfaces tells you what is going on.

Comment: I am supposed to write that because it's a part of my project Airline Booking ,,,, Let me explain the project to u in a nutshell:

Comment: I m supposed to use that because it's a part of my project Airline Booking Let me explain the project to u in a nutshell: I am supposed to create an interface Basic that declares all the methods i will use. then there is the abstract class Structure which implements theinterface and has common methods of all the next three classes viz Economy,Business, Premium Economy.For eg. the method name() is common in all so it is used here.Now the 3 individual classes extend the class Structure and find charge of travelling by air.So this is my project and thats why i m supposed to name the class Economy

Answer (score 0):

Think about what someone would need to know if they wanted to use your class, or a basic description of the class you would give to someone if they didn't know what it did. Why would someone use your class? What does it do?

@Jägermeister mentioned how fallible code comments can be, so make sure that whatever you write, you keep it updated with what your code does. If you change the class, make sure you change your description of the class as well. And keep your description fairly short, you should most likely only need a few lines or less.

If you find yourself writing several lines of description, it might be a good idea to look at your class, and ask yourself if it's trying to do too much. In this case, it might be a good idea to make another class to accept some of its responsibilities.